# Данные из POST в эту же форму через ajax

Tags: ajax

Есть такая форма

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Название</legend>
        <div class="input-form">
            <div class="input_text">Тип товара</div>
            <select class="select select_type" name="type">
                <option value="admin">Админка</option>
                <option value="vip">VIP</option>
                <option value="unban">Разбан</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['type'])):
            switch($_POST['type']):
                case "admin":
        ?>
            <div class="input-form">
                <div class="input_text">Админ группа</div>
                <input type="text" name="param">
            </div>
        <?php 
            break;
            case "vip":
        ?>
            <div class="input-form">
                <div class="input_text">VIP группа</div>
                <input type="text" name="param">
            </div>
        <?php
            break;
            endswitch;
            endif;
        ?>
</fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="save" value="Сохранить">
```

И есть такой js код

```
$('select.select_type').on('change', function() {
      var type = this.value;
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: window.location.href, 
                    data: 'type='+type,
                success:function(result){
                    }
                });
    });
```

Как сделать, чтоб при выборе типа в **select** отображались нужные поля?
Если отправлять данные через кнопку "Сохранить", то работает, а просто при выборе в **select** - нет

Comment: Может вам нужен всё же `location.pathname`, а не `location.href` ?

Comment: при `location.pathname` запрос передается в "/", а при `location.href` на ту страницу куда надо

Answer (score 1):

Просто не передавайте параметр `url` и тогда будет происходить посыл запроса на ту же страницу

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',        
    data: 'type='+type,
    success:function(result){
    }
});
```

Comment: Тоже не работает. Проблема скорее всего не именно в отправке запроса, а в том, что после этого не подгружаются нужные поля

Comment: @lar1ch логично, в `success` у вас пусто)) а в PHP даже не имею понятия что написано ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: в форме есть switch, который выводит необходимые поля! проблема в том что с кнопкой submit всё работает, а если отправлять через ajax, то нет

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем то что хотелось, но работает)

```
$('select.select_type').on('change', function() {
  updateForm($(this).closest("form"));
});
function updateForm(myform)
{
    $(myform).submit();
}
```